# How does `cat` work in ipython interactive shell?

Tags: python, shell, ipython, interactive

I noticed that using `cat` on a file works in ipython. It doesn't appear to be listed as a magic command... so I am confused how/why it works. What lets `cat` work in ipython interactive shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat` is one of the pre-defined system command aliases. Type `%alias` to see the list of aliases in your current ipython session.

Answer (score 5):

IPython automatically defines some shell aliases, including `cat`, [in `IPython.core.alias.default_aliases()`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/alias.py#L43).